# How to print maximum and average of the rest for every row

Tags: awk

Is it possible to print like this may be using awk ?

input

```
        t1      t2      t3      t4      tn
l1      0       0.1448  0.2295  0.2896  0.3362
l3      0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.4421
l4      0.5779  0.138   0.09591 0.05014 0.138
```

output

```
        t1      t2      t3      t4      tn      max      avg.of.rest
l1      0       0.1448  0.2295  0.2896  0.3362  0.3362  0.166
l3      0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.4421  0.4421  0.140
l4      0.5779  0.138   0.09591 0.05014 0.138  0.5779  0.114
```

Comment: I THINK what you might mean by "average of min" is actually "average of the rest of the numbers" since the average of the min numbers would be the min number which in the first row would be zero. If that's right then please edit your question to fix that. Also, add the expected output for every row of sample input. No point giving us one without the other. Hang on - how can the average of the "min" numbers (`0.4467`) be greater than the max number (`0.3362`)? Edit your question to clarify and/or fix mistakes.

Comment: corrected now. there was typo. sorry

Comment: OK, now change one of the input lines such that the max value appears twice and show the expected output for that case. You might also want to add a line where all of the values are zero as that's often a case people don't consider and leads to divide by zero errors when it happens. What about negative numbers?

Comment: What numbers is that average coming from ??

Comment: @ Ed Morton. yes you are right. before this I wrote a script that removes all the rows that has zeroes. And I do not have any numbers because i log2 transform them. @JID. Mean is coming from all the values of each row except the maximum number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t"; OFMT="%.3f" }
NR==1 {
    print $0, "max", "avg.of.rest"
    next
}
{
    max = $2
    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
        max = ($i > max ? $i : max)
    }

    tot = cnt = 0
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i != max) {
            tot += $i
            cnt++
        }
    }

    print $0, max, (cnt?tot/cnt:0)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
        t1      t2      t3      t4      tn      max     avg.of.rest
l1      0       0.1448  0.2295  0.2896  0.3362  0.3362  0.166
l3      0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.4421  0.4421  0.140
l4      0.5779  0.138   0.09591 0.05014 0.138   0.5779  0.106
```

Comment: I actually understand what OP wanted to do more from your answer than their question ha! +1

Comment: Hi I am passing your script to divide max with avg. but I am not getting the header in the ouput. any suggestion would be appreciated. I did like this awk 'NR>1{ if($NF>0) print $0"\t"$(NF-1)/$NF; else print $0"\t"$(NF-1)}

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're talking about. Maybe you should post a new question?