# how to include header using awk

Tags: awk

I am missing header even after using NR>1. Any suggestions ?

cat rm2

```
        t1      t2      t3      t4      tn      max     avg.of.rest
l1      0       0.1448  0.2295  0.2896  0.3362  0.3362  0.166
l3      0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.4421  0.4421  0.140
l4      0.5779  0.138   0.09591 0.05014 0.138   0.5779  0.106

awk 'NR>1{ if($NF>0) print $0"\t"$(NF-1)/$NF; else print $0"\t"$(NF-1)}' rm2

l1      0       0.1448  0.2295  0.2896  0.3362  0.3362  0.166   2.0253
l3      0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.1395  0.4421  0.4421  0.140   3.15786
l4      0.5779  0.138   0.09591 0.05014 0.138   0.5779  0.106   5.45189
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk 'NR==1; NR>1 ....' file`

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do would be written:

```
awk 'NR>1{$0=$0"\t"$(NF-1)/($NF?$NF:1)}1' rm2
```

but why are you doing that instead of just tweaking the script you already got (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28988712/1745001) to print an extra field at the end by simply changing this line:

```
print $0, max, (cnt?tot/cnt:0)
```

to:

```
ave = (cnt?tot/cnt:0)
print $0, max, ave, (ave?max/ave:max)
```